# how to set time for Ajax Markup in wicket

Tags: wicket

I have a link in my page, which implements the IAjaxIndicatorAware interface in wicket. On clicking the link the Wicket Ajax markup shows up. My server is waiting in backend for a service to complete. So what should I do to retain the Ajax Markup for a set amount of time. How to configure the time for the markup. And when the time completes how to send an error message so that it can be shown in the browser.

Comment: The question is not very clear. Please give more details.

Comment: I think this might be what you're looking for http://my3java.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/handling-session-timeout-in-wicket.html